# En Excel, al intentar copiar un rango de celdas a otro libro se deshabilita la opción de pegar y no se puede pegar

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un libro de Excel con macros con varios Formularios.
Y ahora ultimo necesite copiar algunos datos de celdas a otro libro y note que al hacer clic en el libro destino, las celdas marcadas para copiar pierden la linea punteada y el botón para pegar del libro destino se deshabilita, por tal motivo no puedo copiar o sacar la información.
Pero a la inversa funciona normal, es decir, si puedo copiar de otro libro al libro de trabajo con macros y también dentro del mismo libro si permite copiar, pero no hacia otros libros. La única forma fue copiar toda la hoja desde el menú de la pestaña de la hoja "Mover o copiar..."

Quizá tenga que ver con estas lineas donde utilizo el comando 'copy':

En esta parte copio una fila de la hoja 4 a la hoja 5

```
uFL = Hoja5.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row + 1
Hoja4.Rows(Fila).Copy Destination:=Hoja5.Cells(uFL, 1)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Y en esta otra hago una copia del archivo

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Ruta2 & Separador & NombreArchivo
```

Es de anotar que el archivo funciona bien, excepto copiar a otro libro.

Muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme, ya que no he podido encontrar el porque sucede.

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguna persona le pueda suceder mi situación con el 'Copiar y Pegar' entre libros de Excel.

Dentro del libro con macros, en algún momento utilice este procedimiento para no permitir insertar hojas nuevas en el libro, después decidí no usarlo y solamente lo comente y ahí estaba el origen del problema.

```
'Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
'    Application.EnableEvents = False
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'    Sh.Delete
'    MsgBox "No se pueden insertar nuevas hojas en éste libro de Excel."
'    Application.EnableEvents = True
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End Sub
```

Y buscando las posibles casusas que hacían que el icono de 'Pegar' se desactivara al cambiar a otro libro, encontré lo siguiente:

> El uso del evento Worksheet_SelectionChange borrará el Portapapeles, lo que deshabilita la opción Pegado especial. Para habilitarla, debe establecer el valor de la propiedad Application.EnableEvents en False.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/troubleshoot/excel/paste-special-missing-or-not-working

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario usar `.Copy`, puedes definir un rango y luego obtener su valor con `.Value`, es decir, si defines el rango de origen y destino, con `.Value` puedes pasar la información al otro libro.

Este es un ejemplo donde desde el libro activo se pasan datos a otro libro.

```
Sub testCopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim libroOrigen As Workbook, libroDestino As Workbook
    Dim hojaOrigen As Worksheet, hojaDestino As Worksheet
    Dim filaOrigen As Range, filaDestino As Range
    
    Set libroOrigen = ThisWorkbook
    Set libroDestino = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\formu\Desktop\test.xlsx")
    Set hojaOrigen = libroOrigen.Sheets("Hoja1")
    Set hojaDestino = libroDestino.Sheets("Hoja2")
    Set filaOrigen = hojaOrigen.Rows(3)
    Set filaDestino = hojaDestino.Rows(hojaDestino.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    
    filaDestino.Value = filaOrigen.Value
    
    libroDestino.Save
    libroDestino.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Adicionalmente, comentar que `.Copy` es muy lento, si son unos pocos datos y un proceso sencillo, seguramente no lo notaras, pero si se realizara un procedimiento donde cientos de veces se copie y peguen datos, seria sumamente lento, en cambio, el ejemplo que he puesto es mas rápido, la parte mas lenta en ese caso es abrir, guardar y cerrar el libro de destino.